# Adding multiples of 3 and 5 less than 1000

Tags: python

I am trying to find the sum of the multiples of 3 and 5 while the sum is less than 1000. When I run the code, I just get a never ending list of 0s and it says 'Too much output to process'. I don't know where I am going wrong and would appreciate feed back.

```
result = 0
while result <= 1000:
    i = 0
    if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
        print i
        result += i
else:
    i += 1
```

**EDIT**

The loop resets i to 0 everytime. This means that it is always less than 1000.

Comment: Your else is aligned to the while (it is a thing in python), not the if. Also, you should increase i everytime and start i outside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You had an infinite loop because `i` wasn't incremented, and `result` either.

It then boils down to what you want exactly :

## sum less than 1000

```
result = 0
i = 0 
while result <= 1000:
    i += 1
    if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
        result += i

print(result - i)
# 998
```

## elements less than 1000

If you're refering to the [Euler problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1), then the sum shouldn't be less than 1000, but the elements :

```
total_sum = 0
for i in range(1000):
    if (i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0):
        total_sum = total_sum + i
print total_sum  
# 233168
```

An alternative would be :

```
sum(set(range(0,1000,3)) | set(range(0,1000,5)))
# 233168
```

or :

```
sum(range(0,1000,3)) + sum(range(0,1000,5)) - sum(range(0,1000,15))
# 233168
```

Comment: @Elmex80s No problem. Boolean logic doesn't always seem very logical :)

Comment: But you did receive my +1 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A fun exercise is to rewrite this in a more "pythonic" manner, for instance:

```
sum(filter(lambda x: x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0, xrange(1000)))
```

or even better:

```
sum(x for x in xrange(1000) if x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0)
```

which both give `233168` as a result.

(Please note that in both cases `sum()` is a Python builtin function).

By the way, in your problem statement, you mention "less than 1000", but your code includes 1000 in the loop.

Comment: I'm not sure if the description or the code is wrong. OP says that the sum should be less than 1000.

Answer (score 0):

You never increment i. Put i = 0 outside of the loop, and i += 1 inside of it. i.e.

```
result = 0
i = 0

while result <= 1000:
    if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
        print(i)
        result += i
    i += 1
```

Comment: This is one of the first Euler problem, maybe you should add the O(1) solution of it, or at least mention it. AP(3, 1..1000) + AP(5, 1..1000) - AP(15, 1..1000)

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum(): 
    result = 0
    i = 0
    # Put i=0 before loop begin
    while result <= 1000:
        if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
            print i
            result += i
            i+=1  # Put i+=1 after result here
        else:
            i += 1
    print ("sum= "+str(result))
sum()
```

Just put i=0 before the loop begins and i+=1 after result

Comment: You might want to test your code before posting it as an answer.

Comment: you would be right to be honest, i believe this works fine.

Comment: Is the sum smaller than 1000?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is wondering, this is a classic problem, I know it from Euler project:
https://projecteuler.net/problem=1

Besides all the answers given here, there is an O(1) answer using Arithmetic Progression (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression).

Basically we need to calculate the AP of 3 to the maximum divisor of 3 that is less than a 1000 add the AP of 5 to the maximum divisor of 5 that is less than a 1000 minus AP of 15 to the maximum divisor of 15 that is less than a 1000 (this step removes itens that were added twice because they are multiples of 3 and 15).

Here is the code:

```
def ap(i, range_start, range_end):
    a1 = range_start
    an = range_end
    n = (an - a1)/i + 1

    return (a1 + an) * n / 2

def ap_with_limit(i, limit):
    limit -= 1
    return ap(i, i, limit - (limit%i))

print ap_with_limit(3, 1000) + ap_with_limit(5, 1000) - ap_with_limit(15, 1000)
# 233168
```